# C++ SaveFileDialog file icon

Tags: c++, windows, icons, customization, savefiledialog

In C++ using Windows OS, I am using a System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog object to choose a file in which some data will be serialized. I would like to know if it is possible to set a custom icon to the file that will be created. I have set the Filter property to "[ProjectName] file (*.hys)|*.hys" and the file icon is blank, but I would like to assign a custom icon to it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Open or Save file dialog. It is file extension registered with Explorer.

Comment: Thank you @Ajay. So, I know that Explorer will display a specific icon depending on what program is set as default for the file type, but is there no way to change the icon image independently of Explorer ?